# SQlite conditional order

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by, conditional-statements

I have this query:

```
  select id,number,name 
    from objects 
order by case number when 0 then 1 else -1 end asc
```

The database is a database of objects with numbers. If an object doesn't have a number than its number is `0`. I want to sort by number ascending, with the exception of when the number is 0, in which case, sort descending.

The query above seems to sort by ID, the default sorting order.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Close, but you forgot to sort by `number` as well:

```
  SELECT id,number,name 
    FROM objects 
ORDER BY CASE number WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, number;
```

Comment: Hi Adam, that is not working for me, it's just sorting by number asc. The 0 numbers are still first.

Comment: Apologies. I had the sort-order flipped. I've edited to the correct order.